# React Bundle giving error: "Type Error: cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vendor

For the deployed versions of my app, I have added the following code to my Webpack config to grab React from a vendor bundle that I serve:

```
externals: {
   react: 'vendor.React',
   'react-dom': 'vendor.ReactDOM',
},
```

This usually works but for some reason now I am getting the error:

`Type Error: cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined`

Does anyone know what this error is or why my minified react bundle would throw this error?

React Version 16.5.2

Comment: Hmm try checking for updates? https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion/issues/447 
`npm i -g npm-check-updates`
`npm-check-updates -u`
`npm install`
I know it's not the package that you are using but it's worth a try?

Comment: I have tried that, modified my package.json and removed package lock as well. No luck. If it's any help, i'm bundling two different versions in a separate microservice which I then serve the bundle from.

Comment: Hmmmm bear with me on this (I'm doing research on this issue)....  I think the problem is that you have to specify a react and react-dom version... and you put that version in where the package.json specifies your version which is `16.5.2` or you can something specific like https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/826#issuecomment-313793600

Comment: @Demon thanks for trying to help out. I was using the CDN version of React which I downloaded locally on my file-system since I was trying to serve two different versions of React from this micro-service. Turns out the CDN version or React-Dom has require statements:

          require("react"); 

Those require's were resolving to my node_modules which had a lower version of react. The fix was to manually edit those to point to the local filesystem version of React I had downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shoutout to @Demon for trying to help out. Eventual solution was as follows:

I was using the CDN version of React which I downloaded locally on my file-system since I was trying to serve two different versions of React from this micro-service. Turns out the CDN version or React-Dom has require statements:

```
var react = require("react");
```

Those require's were resolving to my node_modules which had a lower version of react. The fix was to manually edit those to point to the local filesystem version of React I had downloaded.

```
var react = require("./react.development.js")
```

Comment: That's great! Glad I could be some of help!